# Access to the generator Gii, Yii2

Tags: yii2

Before I turned on urlManager and wrote rules The Gii-generator worked at

> hostname/index.php?r=gii

After that, I turned on the urlManager hostname/gii does not work
Maybe for him to write a rule? But how?
Options

> 'gii' => 'gii', or 'gii' => 'gii/index',

don't work

```
   'urlManager' => [
       'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
       'showScriptName' => false,
       'rules' => [
           '/' => 'site/index',
           'about' => 'site/about',
           'contact' => 'site/contact',
           'login' => 'site/login',
           'entry' => 'site/entry',
           'gii' => 'gii',
           'country/page/<page:\d+>' => 'country/index',
       ],
   ],
```

Comment: Your turning on could refer [Using Pretty URLs in urlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls) with [Web server Configuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-apache-configuration).

Comment: update your question and show your urlManager config .. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either remove the `gii` entry and the gii module would be accessible with the default route
or somehow specify a complete rule for it

```
'gii/<controller:[a-z-]+>/<action:[a-z-]+>' => 'gii/<controller>/<action>'
```

also here's a [nicer example](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/enable-pretty-urls/) on how to remove the `/site` parameter of the url

Answer (score 0):

it seems your rewrite module causing the issue.

just simply create a file at root of your app dir named as `.htaccess` and paste this code.

```
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and remove url rules for `gii`
so your url rules look like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
   'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
   'showScriptName' => false,
   'rules' => [
       '/' => 'site/index',
       'about' => 'site/about',
       'contact' => 'site/contact',
       'login' => 'site/login',
       'entry' => 'site/entry',
       'country/page/<page:\d+>' => 'country/index',
   ],
```

],

now access `gii` like this:

```
yourhost/your_app_dir/gii
```

one more thing it is work only on `localhost` for live server you need to allow access with `ip address`.

that's it.
Thank You